# Generate data points for a Gaussian with drawing probability

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I am trying to solve this question:

> Generate 500 data points drawn from each of 3 (three) Gaussians: $N_1(1, 0.1)$, $N_2(1.5., 0.1)$ and $N_3(2, 0.2)$ whose drawing probability on each iteration are $P(1) = 0.25$, $P(2) = 0.50$, and $P(3) = 0.25$.

Can someone explain to me what the "drawing probability" is? I understand how to generate random points from the distribution but not with a specific probability.

Comment: I suspect you will only get educated guesses concerning what "drawing probability" could possibly mean. (Your [tag:gaussian-mixture] tag is a hint, but it strongly suggests you haven't supplied enough information.)  Have you consulted the person who set you this problem to ask for clarification?  If they're not available, could you please quote the problem *exactly*?

Comment: @whuber I didn't quote the exact problem because this is for an assignment that I haven't been able to get help with. Here it is - " Generate 500 data points drawn from each of 3 (three) Gaussians:
N1 (1, 0.1), N2 (1.5., 0.1) and N3 (2,  0.2) whose drawing probability on each iteration
are P (1) = 0.25, P(2) = 0.50, and P(3) = 0.25". Once I generate this I have to derive the Gaussian Mixture Model for all the data points combined.

Comment: Therein lies the missing information.  It's best to quote assignments exactly and to add the [tag:self-study] tag.  That lets people know you want help with the concepts, not just an answer.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of the self-study tag. I'll keep that in mind, thanks'

Comment: The phrase "on each iteration" that you omitted makes a difference. The phrasing in the actual question is less confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to draw from a mixture of Gaussians.

First choose which component to draw from (according to the probabilities) and then sample from the corresponding Gaussian.

That is, generate $I = \{1,2,3\}$ with $p_i=P(I=i) = \{.25,.5,.25\}$ respectively.

Then once you know $i$, simulate from a Gaussian with mean $\mu_i$ and variance $\sigma^2_i$ (or possibly the intent there is to specify $\sigma_i$ rather than $\sigma^2_i$), as given in your question.